# Find out if install script runs on mac or linux machine

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to find out if my install scrip is running on a Mac or Linux device.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the uname program. On linux uname returns 'Linux', on Leopard it returns 'Darwin'